# Google drive search : files own by me but not in any folder (previously in a shared folder but now deleted)

Tags: google-drive-api

I got some Google Drive folders shared with me by a collaborator, I put a lot of files into it and we did work like this for months now.

This guy did a delete on the folder and now my files are all lost, I can make a search for my files but there are so many and I don't know the names of all those files.

Is there a way to make a search on those files not listed in any folders but owned by me?

Comment: Have you tried checking in the trash folder of  the collaborator's drive? Usually once you delete a file or folder it goes into trash folder. He can restore the folder from his trash and you will be able to access the files again. Tried this scenario and able to get the deleted folder and files. You could also try checking in the recent folder to get the list of files you recently accessed. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. because the files are owned by me, it's supposed to be in my trash but it's not and like i said, i can find them with the search bar but when i found one, there is no location folder...just look "lost"

Comment: Did you try checking in recent folder?

Comment: Hi, I did but there are some items weren't in this view because i didn't work on those files for weeks.

Answer (score 12):

in your drive, search for

> is:unorganized owner:me

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6008339?hl=en

Answer (score 4):

Had the EXACT same problem. Found this thread by Googling, but had a harder time finding a complete solution. Found it here from Ally Marie:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/xOvsElpcPZA

Synopsis: You can get a list of everything you own and look for the item in that list. Click the down arrow in the Google Drive search box and select Ownership > Owned by me.